# My react state doesn't work in functions, but works when being rendered

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Reactjs, the database I'm using is firestore, and I'm using moments.js

---

**Problem:**

My state is "half" working. When I call it from state.availability inside a function, it will return it's initial state and not the data I loaded into it. However, when I call state.availability from the render, it works and shows the loaded data.

**Expected Results:**

When in a function, state.availability should be returning the data I loaded into it.

**Actual Results:**

It returns it's initial data.

---

I am getting data from my database that contains employee availability. This is called when the page loads using "useEffect":

```
const LoadEmployeeData = async () => {
await props.firestore
  .collection("employeeData")
  .where("userID", "==", props.searchID)
  .get()
  .then(function (e) {
    setState({
      availability: [
        [
          e.docs[0].data().availability.availability.sun[0],
          e.docs[0].data().availability.availability.sun[1],
        ],
        [
          e.docs[0].data().availability.availability.mon[0],
          e.docs[0].data().availability.availability.mon[1],
        ],
        [
          e.docs[0].data().availability.availability.tue[0],
          e.docs[0].data().availability.availability.tue[1],
        ],
        [
          e.docs[0].data().availability.availability.wed[0],
          e.docs[0].data().availability.availability.wed[1],
        ],
        [
          e.docs[0].data().availability.availability.thu[0],
          e.docs[0].data().availability.availability.thu[1],
        ],
        [
          e.docs[0].data().availability.availability.fri[0],
          e.docs[0].data().availability.availability.fri[1],
        ],
        [
          e.docs[0].data().availability.availability.sat[0],
          e.docs[0].data().availability.availability.sat[1],
        ],
      ],
    });
  });
};
```

This is what the database looks like:

[image: Image of database]

I'm using a calendar component I wrote to select the date. When a date on the calendar is selected, I run a function for getting the day of the week and then returning a set of divs representing days available (note: the code for this is still very early):

```
// Gets the date Avaliable
const LoadDay = async (d) => {  
var tempdaySlot = [];

var day = moment().year(d.year).month(d.month).date(d.day).day();
setState({
  datePicked: moment().year(d.year).month(d.month).date(d.day).day(),
});

for (
  var i = state.availability[day][0];
  i < state.availability[day][1];
  i++
) {
  tempdaySlot.push(<div style={LocalStyles.daySlot}></div>);
}

setState({ daySlot: tempdaySlot });
};
```

d is just an object from the calendar ex: {day:1,month:6,year:1982}. My issue is that state.availability always returns its initial values ([1,24]) and not the values within my database. Initially I thought my data wasn't being filled into the state, however I decided to have the data rendered out on the page and the appropriate values are there:

```
return (
<div>
  <Calender language={props.language} ReturnDay={(d) => LoadDay(d)} />
  {state.datePicked !== null ? (
    <div>
      {props.language.Calender.Days[state.datePicked]}
      <p />
      {state.availability[state.datePicked][0]} -{" "}
      {state.availability[state.datePicked][1]}
      <p />
      <Grid
        container
        direction="row"
        justify="flex-start"
        alignItems="center"
      >
        {state.daySlot}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  ) : null}
</div>
);
```

[image: Results in the browser]

Lastly, I have placed "console.log"s through out my code. I had them after the state was being set, and in my GetDate function and everytime the state.availability returned it's initial values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it was my Calendar component that was causing the issue. I decided to have the "ReturnDay" set a day picked state instead of calling a function directly. Then I have the function run outside of that when the state is changed.

```
return (
<div>
  <Calender
    language={props.language}
    ReturnDay={(d) => setState({ datePicked: d })}
  />
  {state.datePicked !== null ? <RenderDay /> : null}
</div>
);
```

RenderDay basically is my LoadDay function with an added return part. This solved my issue.

```
const RenderDay = () => {
    var day = moment()
      .year(state.datePicked.year)
      .month(state.datePicked.month)
      .date(state.datePicked.day)
      .day();
    var tempdaySlot = [];
    for (
      var i = state.availability[day][0];
      i <= state.availability[day][1];
      i++
    ) {
      tempdaySlot.push(<div style={LocalStyles.daySlot}>{i}</div>);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {state.datePicked.day} - {state.datePicked.month} -{" "}
        {state.datePicked.year}
        <p />
        {props.language.Calender.Days[day]} <p />
        <Grid
          container
          direction="row"
          justify="flex-start"
          alignItems="center"
        >
          {tempdaySlot}
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  };
```